# Nominating a professor for a fellowship

Tags: professorship, awards, acm

I know a professor who is really brilliant, but also very modest. This professor has helped me to progress in life. Now, I want to express my gratitude by nominating him as [ACM Fellow](http://awards.acm.org/fellow/). However, I have no experience in situations of this kind and I would like to ask you a couple of questions:

1. When you are nominating a professor for a fellow title, do you need to ask permission to him? or should I keep the process in secrecy?
2. In case the fellow title may not be granted to him, could this fact hurt his reputation?
3. Is it ethical to try convince other professors to support my nomination application?

Comment: Hi, and welcome to Academia.SE! This is a nice first question. Have you read the [ACM guidelines for nominations](http://awards.acm.org/FellowNominationGuidelines.pdf)? That should take care of your third question, since you already need five endorsers who are ACM members.

Comment: What a kind person you are. No matter how this turns out, I believe your professor will be grateful.

Answer (score 22):

First make sure that you have read all the regulations for the award (in the case of ACM fellows: http://awards.acm.org/fellow_nom_guide.cfm). You see that the nomination in this case is quite some work. Especially question 3 is already answered there: You need five endorsers. Hence, it is expected that you "convince five people to support the nomination".

For question 2 it seems pretty clear that the ACM fellowship is really very competitive, so not getting the fellowship will not really hurt (not getting the Nobel price is also not a big deal for most people).

For question 1: In my opinion you do not need to ask for permission. The awardees do not have any obligations so they will not have any burden from this award. I also think (but I am not sure about this) that is usual to not inform people that you want to nominate them. However, you need to provide a lot of information to the award giving institution and it is also not unusual to ask the person that you want to nominate "I (better: We) plan to nominate you for this award and would appreciate if you could provide us this and that information to prepare the nomination."

Comment: That's all great information. I should also say that for an ACM fellowship, being "brilliant" and kind is by itself not enough. One also needs to be (very) accomplished in one's field of research, and the proposers / endorsers themselves also need to be rather high-profile. It's not really appropriate as a sort of "thank you note" to a good mentor, as the OP seems to envision.

Answer (score 8):

It's great that you would like to help your mentor, but this is a tricky issue.

First, writing a good nomination is not easy, and it's far from obvious what the conventions are.  If you don't get advice and guidance from someone more experienced, you are unlikely to write a successful nomination.

Second, nominators are usually senior and accomplished academics, typically fellows themselves or scholars of equivalent stature.  (I don't know for sure about the ACM, but this is the case for analogous mathematical societies.)  This isn't strictly necessary, but the committee will generally not have any expertise in the specific subject matter of each nomination, so they need to be able to rely on the judgment and perspective of the nominator.  If you are young or inexperienced, then the committee will be much more skeptical of your nomination.  In extreme cases they might not take it seriously at all.

> In case the fellow title may not be granted to him, could this fact hurt his reputation?

That won't be a problem in itself.  However, the situation might look bad to the committee.  Self-nominations are generally highly discouraged, if they are allowed at all, so people who wish to become fellows sometimes ask other people to nominate them.  The committee might wonder whether your mentor asked you to do this, in which case choosing someone inexperienced could make your mentor look unwise.

> When you are nominating a professor for a fellow title, do you need to ask permission to him? or should I keep the process in secrecy?

You don't need to ask permission in general.  It's unclear to me whether you should do so here.  On the one hand, it's an unusual situation and your mentor might prefer not to be nominated under these circumstances.  On the other hand, he might feel put on the spot, having to either agree to be nominated or find a tactful way of declining.

My recommendation is that you should find another way to express your gratitude, since this nomination is unlikely to work and could be awkward.  (But I don't mean this as criticism: there's no way you could have known this without more experience.)

Instead of writing a nomination yourself, you could talk with other faculty about whether they would be willing to do it, but don't push them if they seem reluctant.